# Popup message makes the page scroll down. I need to fix this HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

Im making a FQA page and I want when I click on the question to popup the answer below the question. Everything is working fine expect that, when I click the question the answer is showing but the problem is that page scrolls down a little bit and the question is dissapears to the top and its not user friendly.

Now I will show:
[Before the click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E46R9.png)

[After the question click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA9tq.png)
As you can see the answer is displaying but the scroll moves automatically down and this hides the question, you have to scroll a little bit up to view it.

[As you can see when I scroll up everything is fine and working, but I want to fix this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLGdN.png)

This is my html and css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FQA</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

        *,
        *::before,
        *::after
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }
        
        html
        {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-size: 10px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        section
        {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #03a9f4;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
        
        .container
        {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0 1.5rem;
        }
        
        .accordion-item
        {
            background-color: #283042;
            border-radius: .4rem;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            padding: 1rem;
            box-shadow: .5rem 2px .5rem rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        }
        
        .accordion-link
        {
            font-size: 1.6rem;
            color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #283042;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 1rem 0;
        }
        
        .accordion-link i
        {
            color: #e7d5ff;
            padding: .5rem;
        }
        
        .accordion-link .ion-md-remove
        {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .answer
        {
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #212838;
            transition: max-height 650ms;
        }
        
        .answer::before
        {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: .6rem;
            height: 90%;
            background-color: #8fc460;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
        
        .answer p
        {
            color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
            font-size: 1.4rem;
            padding: 2rem;
        }
        
        .accordion-item:target .answer
        {
            max-height: 20rem;
        }
        
        .accordion-item:target .accordion-link .ion-md-add
        {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .accordion-item:target .accordion-link .ion-md-remove
        {
            display: block;
        }
        
.header {
  padding: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  background:
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: black;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

        @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
  <h1 style="font-size:80px">FQA</h1>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
<br>
</div>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="accordion">
                    <div class="accordion-item" id="question1">
                        <a class="accordion-link" href="#question1">
                            Сколько мне должно быть лет, чтобы арендовать машину в Бургас?
                            <i class="icon ion-md-add"></i>
                            <i class="icon ion-md-remove"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="answer">
                            <p>В большинстве случаев у вас должен быть минимум 23 года и минимум 3 полных стажа вождения.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-item" id="question2">
                        <a class="accordion-link" href="#question2">
                            Окончательны ли предложения по аренде автомобилей Бургас?
                            <i class="icon ion-md-add"></i>
                            <i class="icon ion-md-remove"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="answer">
                            <p>Да, все комиссии и сборы четко указаны в предложении.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-item" id="question3">
                        <a class="accordion-link" href="#question3">
                            Дополнительный водитель для аренда авто в Бургас?
                            <i class="icon ion-md-add"></i>
                            <i class="icon ion-md-remove"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="answer">
                            <p>Если в найме участвуют более одного водителя, второй и все последующие драйверы называются дополнительными.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-item" id="question4">
                        <a class="accordion-link" href="#question4">
                            Взимается ли плата, если вы не приедете после бронирования для аренда автомобиля в Бургас?
                            <i class="icon ion-md-add"></i>
                            <i class="icon ion-md-remove"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="answer">
                            <p>Нет, политика Fiesta Rent a Car Burgas заключается в приеме заявок (и при необходимости аннулирования) по телефону и на веб-сайте. В Fiesta Rent A Car Burgas мы не берем у вас данные кредитной карты перед арендой, поэтому нет возможности взимать с вас плату, если вы отмените бронирование для аренда авто в Бургас в последнюю минуту или не явитесь.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no issue in FAQ's but your header looks like a fixed (Position: fixed;)
that is the main reason for hiding behind the header.
Simple Solution: when the first child clicked; set margin-top: 50px; or according to your desire.